# How to clear a click() when another click() is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have a complicated issue on click(). I am having 4 buttons named as function 1 , function 2, method 1 and method 2.

```
<button id="function1"> Function 1</button>
<button id="function2">Function 2</button>
<button id="method1">Method 1</button>
<button id="method2">Method 2</button>
```

When function 1 in clicked and method 1 is clicked i have to trigger a action like this

```
 $("#function1").click(function(){
 $('#method1').click(function(){
 $('#section1').html('<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/myvector/myvector1201/myvector120102079/12127940-  vector-illustration-of-single-isolated-airport-icon.jpg"/>');
  });
});
```

Like this i have four different combinations for function 1 method 1,function 1 method 2,function 2 method 1,function 2 method 2.

The problem is when i selected function 1 with any method it works fine. When i select function 2 after selecting the function 1 it changes both values.

I want to clear the previous click() and the change must happen only for the selected combination.

I have added a [BIN](http://jsbin.com/ilerej/1/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you're binding the click handler to `"#method1"` **inside** the click handler of `"#function1"`?

Comment: How about storing which buttons have been pressed and act correspondingly?

Comment: Because it activates only if the #function1 is clicked

Comment: @zerkms i have a lot of click() involving so i selected this method

Comment: @Vivek Dragon: which "this" method exactly? The one you're currently using doesn't work (because it's just wrong). And how saving the state correlates with number of buttons/click handlers?

Comment: I got it now @T.J.Crowder posted the answer which i have to add .unbind("click") to the click() of #method1. Its working correctly. Check this http://jsbin.com/ilerej/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind), which removes event handlers. [Updated Bin](http://jsbin.com/ilerej/2).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried but it locks the function not stoping the change

Comment: Yeah thats what i need. thanks @T.J.Crowder i tried to make it after the event so its didnt workred for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is good idea to play with binding for sequential clicks. Creates some variables to contains the click sequences and check if the sequence match what you are interested. This is just an example:

```
var prevClick = '';
var currClick='';

function doClick() {
    var name = $(this).attr("id");
    prevClick = currClick;
    currClick = name;
    checkSequence();
}

function checkSequence() {
    // Check the sequence.
    if ((prevClick == 'function1') && (currClick == 'method1'))
    {
      $('#section1').html('<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/myvector/myvector1201/myvector120102079/12127940-  vector-illustration-of-single-isolated-airport-icon.jpg"/>');
    }
}

$(function(){
   // Assume that you only this four buttons.
   // Otherwise put more specific jQuery selector like adding a class.
   $("button").click(doClick);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.click is used to add an event handler. Your will add one event handlers to 'method1' when you click 'function1'/'function2' button. For example when user click 'function1' 2 times, 'function2' 3 times. The 'method1' will have 5 event handlers, 2 for 'function1', 3 for 'function2'. This is not a good design.

For your purpose. Here is a solution:

```
var funType = 0;
$("#function1").click(function(){
   funType = 1;
});
$("#function2").click(function(){
   funType = 2;
});

$('#method1').click(function(){
   if(funType  == 1){
      //function1 is clicked
   }
   else if(funType  == 2){
      //function2 is clicked
   }
});

$('#method2').click(function(){
   if(funType  == 1){
      //function1 is clicked
       }
   else if(funType  == 2){
      //function2 is clicked
   }
 });
```